# Keeping in ablution where the cold makes it difficult to maintain

Tags: salat, wudu

I'm from Pakistan and we don't have gas in winters here to warm up water and less electricity in summers. Especially in winters, as there is no hot water and its already 1 C and no way to get a shower to clean up. How does one keep in wadu (ablution) when one might be married and had a sexual timing and need a bath.

What does the Qur'an says about that kind of situation, because many of my namaz get missed because I live in a poor country and I am asthmatic and cannot shower with cold water or use cold water in winters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actions which have the tendency to keep one from his/her obligations should be refrained from. Carnal and marital needs and obligations (Haq-un-Nas) don't have a higher precedence than religious obligations (Haq-ullah).

E.g. to prove the point, obligatory fast don't need husband's consent, while the non-obligatory ones do.

But if one inadvertently gets into a state where one has to perform ablution, but medical conditions and/or environmental conditions don't permit then one should perform the dry ablution (not getting into the details of it) and perform his/her obligations.

Certainly and definitely one shouldn't forgo prayer because of the above mentioned.

> *What does Quran says about that kind of situation*

These are some relevant to your situation:

> O ye who believe! Approach not prayers with a mind befogged, until ye can
>   understand all that ye say,- nor in a state of ceremonial impurity [Except when
>   travelling on the road], until after washing your whole body. **If ye are ill, or on a journey, or one of you cometh from offices of nature, or ye have been in
>   contact with women, and ye find no water, then take for yourselves clean sand or
>   earth, and rub therewith your faces and hands. For Allah doth blot out sins and
>   forgive again and again.** (4:43)
>
> O ye who believe! When ye prepare for prayer, wash your faces, and your hands
>   (and arms) to the elbows; rub your heads (with water); and (wash) your feet to
>   the ankles. If ye are in a state of ceremonial impurity, bathe your whole body.
>   But if ye are ill, or on a journey, or one of you cometh from offices of nature,
>   or ye have been in contact with women, and ye find no water, then take for
>   yourselves clean sand or earth, and rub therewith your faces and hands. **Allah
>   doth not wish to place you in a difficulty, but to make you clean, and to
>   complete His favor to you, that ye may be grateful.** (5:7)

And what does Allah guides and instruct about prayers:

> And be steadfast in prayer; practise regular charity; and bow down your
>   heads with those who bow down [in worship]. (2:43)
>
> O ye who believe! seek help with patient perseverance and prayer; for Allah
>   is with those who patiently persevere. (2:153)
>
> Guard strictly your [habit of] prayers, especially the Middle Prayer; and
>   stand before Allah in a devout [frame of mind]. (2:238)

Comment: when you mention "Guard strictly your [habit of] prayers, especially the Middle Prayer; and stand before Allah in a devout [frame of mind]. (2:238)", what is meant by middle prayer?

Comment: [What does Middle Prayer mean in 2:238?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10663/3487)

Answer (score -1):

If it damages your body and is harmful you must do tayammum, unless ghusl is necessary.

[Shia source:](http://www.leader.ir/tree/index.php?catid=23)

> Q 181: I am faced with a problem, i.e. even a single drop of water is so harmful for my body that even it should not be wiped. While washing my body, even a part of it, my heartbeat increases along with other symptoms. Is it permissible for me in such a condition to have intercourse with my wife, to do tayammum instead of ghusl for several months, and to pray and enter the masjid with this tayammum?
>
> A: It is not obligatory for you to refrain from intercourse and after becoming junub, if you are excused from performing ghusl of janābah, your shar‘ī duty is to do tayammum instead of ghusl for the acts that require ghusl. And with tayammum, there is no impediment to your entering a masjid, offering prayer, touching the script of the Noble Qur’an and all the other acts that require ghusl.

Comment: Your answer is mostly copy-paste. You should have used that source to answer to directly relate to OP's question. Please realize that these types of answers have the potential of shooing away new user and visitor. We do have [ell.se] and [english.se], if you have any question regarding English.