# What does Middle Prayer mean in 2:238?

Tags: salat, tafseer, surat-al-baqarah

In the verse 2:238:

> Guard strictly your [habit of] prayers, especially the Middle Prayer; and stand before Allah in a devout [frame of mind].

What does Middle Prayer mean?

Answer (score 3):

The middle prayer is salat Al Asr

> عَنْ يَحْيَى، سَمِعَ عَلِيًّا، يَقُولُ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله
> عليه وسلم يَوْمَ الأَحْزَابِ وَهُوَ قَاعِدٌ عَلَى فُرْضَةٍ مِنْ فُرَضِ
> الْخَنْدَقِ ‏ "‏ شَغَلُونَا عَنِ الصَّلاَةِ الْوُسْطَى حَتَّى غَرَبَتِ
> الشَّمْسُ مَلأَ اللَّهُ قُبُورَهُمْ وَبُيُوتَهُمْ - أَوْ قَالَ
> قُبُورَهُمْ وَبُطُونَهُمْ - نَارًا ‏"‏ ‏.‏
>
> Yahya heard 'Ali saying that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said on the
> day (of the Battle) of Ahzab, while sitting in one of the openings of
> the ditch: They (the enemies) have diverted us from the middle prayer
> till the sun set. May Allah fill their graves and their houses with
> fire, or their graves and stomachs with fire.

[صحيح مسلم (Muslim)](https://sunnah.com/muslim:627e)